# Server Side Custom Validator Not Firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-4.0

I'm having an odd problem in that one of the 4 custom validators on my web page is not firing.  Everything looks correct based on the working validators.  Below is the simplified code.

ASPX code -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="CMT_TXT" runat="server" Columns="60" Rows="8"
     TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%#Eval("CMT_TXT")%>'></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="csvCMT_TXT" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CMT_TXT"
    Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Msg">
    </asp:CustomValidator>
```

VB code -

```
 Public Sub csvCMT_TXT_ServerValidate(source As Object,
                                   args As ServerValidateEventArgs) _
    Handles csvCMT_TXT.ServerValidate

    dim s As String = CMT_TXT.Text
    args.IsValid = s.Length <= 3500
End Sub
```

When testing,

- The contents of field CMT_TXT has approximately 3000 characters.  So it is not an empty field issue.
- Page.Validate is called in the main body of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a problem with the VS2010 project build.

To this the problem, I had to

1. Deleted all files in BIN directory
2. Deleted all file in OBJ directory
3. Deleted Custom Validator
4. Rebuilt the Project
5. Add Custom Validation back into program.  Added the original code back into program

It's a bit extreme, but this is what it took to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

for server side validation to fire you need to call [Page.Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this should trigger all your server side validation and update Page.IsValid

Also it does not look like you have the event set up on the custom val. may want to add the prop OnServerValidate

```
OnServerValidate="csvCMT_TXT_ServerValidate"


<asp:CustomValidator ID="csvCMT_TXT" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CMT_TXT"
    Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Msg" OnServerValidate="csvCMT_TXT_ServerValidate">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Good point, but this is being done.  I've added this call in the testing conditions of the question.  Sorry if I've caused any confusion.

Comment: @photo_tom, did my edit help any? looks like the event handler is not registered. leaving in the part for the Page.Validate for others who may come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with VB.NET, but with C# I'll check the `Page.IsValid` field before continuing on with a page that has a `CustomValidator`.

An example with a `Wizard` control that contains a `CustomValidator` in the final stage, I will check this value in the `FinishButtonClick` event.

```
protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid == false)
    {
        // validator failed, stop wizard from continuing
        return;
    }

    // page is valid, continue on
    // ...
}
```

Not sure if there are any differences with VB.NET, but may be worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it looks like you named your handler incorrectly. The control ID is `csvCMT_TXT` while the handler is `csv_CMT_TXT.ServerValidate`. There's an extra `_` in the handler.

Comment: It's been a bad day.  You caught a second error in my question.  ARG!!! at myself.